# A single object in Blender = multiple objects in Pepakura

Tags: mesh, objects

As the title says, after using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> shortcut to merge several objects into one, and exporting to OBJ and then opening in Pepakura Designer, it acts as if I never connected them at all.

It's a helmet, and more specifically, the unfold in pepakura unfolds all of the separate objects and, if i managed to assemble all of the parts, I'd finish with 6 unconnected parts instead of a full connected helmet.

So, can anyone help me? I'm extremely new to Blender and have no idea what to do. I've been looking for a few days now.

Thank you all.

Comment: It probably only allows objects to have one mesh, whereas, in Blender, an object can have arbitrarily many.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How would I go about making it one mesh, then?

Comment: By actually connecting the individual parts, vertex by vertex. Is it really crucial that it be one piece? You can probably parent all the pieces to a placeholder or something

Comment: It being one piece makes everything easier. Also, how would I go about doing anything you suggested? I have no idea what to do at all. Thanks!

Comment: It's the boring process of selecting a pair of vertices to merge and pressing Alt + M

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do that it horribly deforms the piece.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using .obj file exange format, Pepakura will import the object exported from Blender as a single object if in blender you join all the geometry in a single object.

Pepakura is an unfolding software. Starting from the given geometry,it caluculates the angles and suggest where to put seams, add labels... but all rely on the initial geometry. If you give it two disconnected pieces, even if they are "the same object" they will be considered disconnected, so their boundaries will obiuvsly be seams.

[image]

[image]

Notice in the images above how pepakura ignores the fact that the cubes are intersected and cosider them as two disjoined cubes (as they are also in Blender, evon though they are stored in the same object).

You should work on your geometry and make all the pieces that you want be connected a whole.

You can use:

- Boolean operations
- Bridge edge loops, or add faces manually or with F2 add-on if the borders are distant
- Remove doubles, if border are almost in the same place
- etc...